# iOS: limit mini height for XIB tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

My tableViewCell's bottom equal to that selected UILabel. But if this label have few words cell's height is too small.
So how can i limit cell's mini height equals to that imageView's bottom?

[image: MY tableViewCell]

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your imageview, label Tittle(Fantastic cos) and label description into a view says it main view. Give the main view constraints left, right top, bottom to the cell and height constant as what you what default cell height.
2. now give contraints to inner components w.r.t. main view:

a) imageview : top, leading, height, width(height is equal to the main view height by constant)

b) label tittle: top wrt main view, leading wrt imageview, trailing wrt main view, and constant height.

c) label description: top wrt label tittle, leading wrt imageview, trailing wrt mainview, bottom wrt main view and height.

3. Now you contraints given by you defines the default tablecell size i.e. whatever your label description text have this size remains atleast and at most.
4. Now we have minimun height of the cell, and now we have to change the height of cell as per our text size. 
   Now, change the both height relation of label descption and main view from equalto(=) to greaterthan or equal(>=).
5. Now with table view delegates impliment these two methods

a)estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath returns (your default tableview height)

b)heightForRowAtIndexPath returns UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

6. Now run and enjoy with tableview. :)

**For More details you can refer :** https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: If my answer is help full for you, then hit like on the answer so that other persons can also get the right answer. Thanks

Comment: You can do with answer.

Comment: If you need any help, you can ask, I will give my best. 
by the way WELCOME. (^.^)